# Increasing the FPS of my openGL Solar System

Tags: c++, opengl

I have a Solar System that is running on a super low fps (about 26). When I run the program with the planets commented out I get about 1500-2000 fps. When I add any planet it drops down to about 400 fps. And then it only goes downhill from there with the more planets I add. The size of the pictures are not that big. The biggest one I have is about 150kb. Even when I reduce it, the fps still drops the same way.
Here is the code for the solar system.

## Updated version using vectors

```
#include <Vrui/Application.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "solarSystem.h"
#include "drawShape.h"
#include "planet.h"
#include "skybox.h"

using namespace std;

double orbitSpeed = 0.0;
double rotatSpeed = 0.0;
vector<Planet>planets;

/****************************************************
 *
 ****************************************************/
SolarSystem::SolarSystem(int& argc,char**& argv) 
:Vrui::Application(argc,argv)
{
    //Vrui::setNavigationTransformation(Vrui::Point::origin,Vrui::Scalar(15));
}

/****************************************************
 *
 ****************************************************/
void SolarSystem::frame(void)
{
    Vrui::scheduleUpdate(Vrui::getApplicationTime()); // Aim for 125 FPS
}

/****************************************************
 *
 ****************************************************/
void SolarSystem::createPlanets() const
{
    planets.push_back(Planet("images/Sun.jpg", 696, 696, 2500, 0.0, 0.0));
    planets.push_back(Planet("images/mercury.jpg", 200.44, 200.44, 57910.0, 45740.0,     0.0));
planets.push_back(Planet("images/venus.jpg", 600.05, 600.05, 108200.0, 107464.0, 177.3));
planets.push_back(Planet("images/earth.jpg", 600.37, 600.34, 149600.0, 147102.0, 23.5));
//planets.push_back(Planet("images/moon.jpg", 300.4, 300.4, 384.0, 363.0, 5.145));
planets.push_back(Planet("images/mars.jpg", 30000.39, 30000.37, 227940.0, 207425.0, 25.2));
planets.push_back(Planet("images/Jupiter.jpg", 69000.9, 65000.24, 778330.0, 740734.0, 3.1));
planets.push_back(Planet("images/neptune.jpg", 24.63, 24.08, 4504300.0, 4460608.0, 29.6));
planets.push_back(Planet("images/pluto.jpg", 10000.15, 10000.15, 5913520.0, 4475140.0, 29.6));
}

/****************************************************
 *
 ****************************************************/
void SolarSystem::displayOrbitPath() const
{
    
glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);
//Orbit Path
glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
//Mercury //1.5849
drawCircle(91781.559, 72493.326, 1, 200);
//Venus
drawCircle(171486.0, 170319.6936, 1, 200);
//Earth     
drawCircle(237101.04, 233141.9598, 1, 200);
//Mars
drawCircle(361262.106, 328747.8825, 1, 200);
//Jupiter
drawCircle(1233575.217, 1173994.071, 1, 200);
//Saturn
drawCircle(1429400.0*1.5849, 1349353.0*1.5849, 1, 100);
//Uranus
drawCircle(2870990.0*1.5849, 2738637.0*1.5849, 1, 100);
//Neptune
drawCircle(7138865.07, 7069617.619, 1, 200);
//Pluto
drawCircle(5913520.0*1.5849, 4475140.0*1.5849, 1, 200);

}


/****************************************************
 *
 ****************************************************/
void SolarSystem::display(GLContextData& contextData) const
{   


displayOrbitPath();

glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);


for(std::vector<Planet>::iterator it = planets.begin(); 
it != planets.end(); 
++it)

{

double plOrbS = orbitSpeed;
double plRotS = rotatSpeed;

  it->displayPlanet(0, plRotS, 0.0,0.0);

}


orbitSpeed+=1;
if (orbitSpeed > 359)
orbitSpeed = 0.0;

    
rotatSpeed+=3;
if (rotatSpeed > 1436.0)
rotatSpeed = 0.0;
    
}

/****************************************************
 *
 ****************************************************/
int main(int argc,char* argv[])
    {

    SolarSystem app(argc, argv);
app.createPlanets();
app.run();

return 0; 
}
```

This is what drops the fps considerably

## Updated

**planet.h**

```
class Planet
{
public:
//Planet();
Planet(const char* fileName, double ER, double PR, 
    double orbitSMa, double orbitSmi, double angle);
~Planet() {};

void setOrbit(double orbitSpeed, double rotationSpeed, 
        double moonOrbitX, double moonOrbitY) ;

    
void displayPlanet(double orbitSpeed, double rotationSpeed, 
            double moonOrbitX, double moonOrbitY);



double getMajorAxis() {return majorAxis;};
double getMinorAxis() {return minorAxis;};
private:
const char* texture;
double equatRadius;
double polarRadius;
double orbitSemiMajor;
double orbitSemiMinor;
double majorAxis;
double minorAxis;   
double orbitAngle;
Images::RGBImage surfaceImage;
};
```

**planet.cpp Updated**

```
#include "planet.h"


Planet::Planet(const char* fileName, double ER, double PR, double orbitSMa, double orbitSMi, double angle)
{
this->texture        = fileName;
this->equatRadius    = ER;
this->polarRadius    = PR;
this->orbitSemiMajor = orbitSMa;
this->orbitSemiMinor = orbitSMi;
this->majorAxis  = 0.0;
this->minorAxis  = 0.0;
this->orbitAngle = angle;

surfaceImage=Images::readImageFile(this->texture);

}

void Planet::setOrbit(double orbitSpeed, double rotationSpeed, 
          double moonOrbitX, double moonOrbitY) 
{
majorAxis = orbitSemiMajor * cos(orbitSpeed * 0.0055555556 * Math::Constants<double>::pi);
minorAxis = orbitSemiMinor * sin(orbitSpeed * 0.0055555556 * Math::Constants<double>::pi);

glTranslate(majorAxis+moonOrbitX, minorAxis+moonOrbitY, 0.0);
glRotatef(orbitAngle, 0.0, 1.0,1.0);
glRotatef(rotationSpeed, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

}

void Planet::displayPlanet(double orbitSpeed,double rotationSpeed, 
           double moonOrbitX, double moonOrbitY)
{

glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
surfaceImage.glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,GL_RGB);

glPushMatrix();
setOrbit(orbitSpeed,rotationSpeed, moonOrbitX, moonOrbitY);
drawSolidPlanet(equatRadius, polarRadius, 1, 40, 40); 
glPopMatrix();

 }
```

I tried creating the planets using vectors, as you can see above, but I still keep getting low FPS when I run the program.

Here are the computer specs:

Video Card: NVIDIA Quadro FX 580 4GB

Computer: Intel Xeon(R) 3.2GHZ 12GB RAM

Comment: Try moving only the first two lines in the constructor. The other four lines are to set up the texture for drawing. The file load is definitly your fps killer.

Comment: Do you call `glBindTexture` before drawing?

Comment: I don't think I ever call `glBindTexture` I think `urfaceImage=Images::readImageFile(this->texture);` does that for me.

Comment: That's why you don't see anything if you don't reupload textures to video memory every frame: you have to bind texture before using it.

Comment: consider updating to the modern API: http://duriansoftware.com/joe/An-intro-to-modern-OpenGL.-Chapter-1:-The-Graphics-Pipeline.html

Answer (score 8):

1. Have a list (e.g. `std::vector<Planet>` of planets in the solarsystem, and only create the planets once (you will need to move them, if you want your solarsystem to have movement.
2. Only read textures as part of the construction, as (I expect) the texture is "constant".
3. in SolarSystem::display() use the list of planets to call `displayPlanet`.

Comment: Bah, your answer is mine, but a minute faster.  You win :)

Comment: Often the case with "fairly obvious answer".

Comment: Agreed.  Doing the whole recreate the solar system every tic thing isn't the best way to do things - especially if the planets are read from disc.  Once that is done, then we can mention the fun of modern OpenGl and VBOs and such.

Answer (score 3):

Does Images::readImageFile do file I/O?  If so, do not call that every tic.  Load it into a buffer/array somewhere one time and then grab the pointer every tic when displaying.  You can do the rest of that function in the display, just not the load.

You are re-creating your planets every tic in display.  Create them once in a create function, place them in a vector or array, and then call those buffered objects.

You also do not mention what the specs of your test computer are.  A low end computer with no real graphics card might struggle with a somewhat complex textured model.

**Edit from comment**

```
// Within your Planet class add this where you have your texture stored:
Images::RGBImage surfaceImage;

// When the texture is setup in your constructor, add
surfaceImage=Images::readImageFile(this->texture);
// And remove it from the drawPlanet call

// Global or in a high visibility scope location
std::vector<Planet> planets;  

// Call this outside of your main run loop
void createPlanets()
{   
  planets.push_back(Planet("images/pluto.jpg", 10000.15, 10000.15, 5913520.0, 4475140.0, 29.6));
  ... // Each planet
}

// And in your main draw loop:
for(std::vector<Planet>::iterator iter = planets.begin(); 
    iter != planets.end(); 
    ++iter)
{
  double plOrbS = orbitSpeed;
  double plRotS = rotatSpeed;

  iter->displayPlanet(plOrbS, plRotS, 0.0,0.0);
}
```

Comment: I added the specs of my computer to my question. Sorry I missed that. How would I load the images to an array?

Comment: Edited with more info for you.

Comment: I'll work on this and let you know how it works out man... thanks a ton for the help!

Comment: do you know how to fix this error `solarSystem.cpp: In member function ‘void SolarSystem::createPlanets()’:
solarSystem.cpp:40:62: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::vector<Planet>::push_back(const char [15], int, int, int, double, double)’
solarSystem.cpp:40:62: note: candidate is:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_vector.h:826:7: note: void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(const value_type&) [with _Tp = Planet, _Alloc = std::allocator<Planet>, std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type = Planet] /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_vector.h:826:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 6 provid`

Comment: I suspect it's because I create empty instances of my planet class inside the vector, and now I'm trying to add data to my variables. How would you get past that?

Comment: The push_back should be creating an instance per call.  You are passing in the constructor's parameters to it - in this case the 6 parameters.  BTW, I forgot to add the Planet callout to my code.  Blind coding and all.  Try the edited version.

Comment: oh, that took care of that problem. I'm now trying to just draw the sun and I have a `cout` inside the `for loop` you showed to test it, but the program never goes inside this loop. Any ideas why? It looks right to me, I don't know what the issue could be

Comment: As long as you have added to that vector, it should go into it 1 per planet.  Perhaps you now have 2 copies of the "planets" var on accident and are accessing a local copy instead?  It could help to repost your newly edited code to help debug it.  I am not the world's greatest C++ programmer being a 99% C programmer for most of my career so other eyes might catch simple bugs that I might miss.  Also make sure you create call is done before your first draw call...

Comment: I was being retarded... I forgot to call the `createPlanets()` function. It's working now, but the fps is still the same... Good try though, I appreciate the help.

Comment: You should make a new question with the new code and perhaps we can try again... :)

Comment: I'm going to modify this one, because the problem is still the same, the code is different. I think if I create a new one they are going to block it claiming it is a copy of another question.

Comment: Perhaps, but the problem and question have changed a bit and a new question will get more eyes.  If you are worried, link the original question in your new and explain how it has changed.  :)

Comment: I modified the question to show my new code. The problem is still the same, I keep getting low fps when I run the program. Both codes gave the same fps as result, that's why I didn't create a new question

Comment: Ok, what does drawSolidPlanets look like?  And do you have access to some sort of profiler that can show you where the slow down is?